# Fighting with ListView

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I have a `ListView` in one fragment in my app, and a button.

The button displays a Dialog, presenting some `CheckBoxes` for the user to select which ones does he/she wish to add to the `ListView`.

That works ok, when the user clicks on the `checkBox`, the item is added to the list, BUT if I click on all the `checkBoxes`, the last item in the `ListView` gets the text  of the first one.

**This is my adapter:**

```
public class ListaTributosAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<ListaTributosBean> data;
private LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public ListaTributosAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ListaTributosBean> data){

    this.data=data;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(c);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.celda_listview_tributos, null);
        TextView texto=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        texto.setText(data.get(position).getTexto());
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

`ListaTributosBean` is a class with just a `TextView`, and an `ImageView` that is not used at this moment.

This is how I set the Adapter, I have an array of `Strings` and an `ArrayList` to store the items the user selected using the

**CheckBoxes:**

```
private String[] opciones={"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
private ArrayList<ListaTributosBean> datos;
```

**I set the adapter to the ListView:**

```
adapter=new ListaTributosAdapter(c, datos);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**I am adding two items to the ArrayList that are mandatory:**

```
datos.add(new ListaTributosBean("Mandatory1"));
datos.add(new ListaTributosBean("Mandatory2"));
```

When the user clicks one button, the **Dialog** with **checkBoxes** is presented:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.selectcheckboxes));
            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(opciones, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {

                        if (datos.get(i).getTexto().equals(opciones[which])) {
                            Toast.makeText(c, getString(R.string.contains1) + " " + opciones[which] + " " + getString(R.string.contains2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            repe = true;
                        } 


                    }
                    if (repe == true) {

                        repe = false;

                    } else {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            datos.add(new ListaTributosBean(opciones[which]));

                        }
                    }

                }
            });

            builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    try {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }).create().show();
        }
    });
```

If I click one `checkBox`, no problem. I click two **checkBoxes**, no problem.

But if I check all five **checkBoxes**, the last item in the `ListView` gets the text of the first one, despite if I click it, and do

```
String selected = ((ListaTributosBean) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getTexto();
```

it returns the correct value.

The rest of items in the `ListView` looks fine, and responds ok when clicked.

**Why is this happening?**

**Can anybody help me?**

Thank you.

Comment: first you implementation of getView is wrong ... if you are using only 1 textview then put it as tag to convertView ... like `TextView txt = null;
if (convertView == null) { /*old code here (without setText)*/ txt = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4); convertView.setTag(txt); } else { txt = (TextView)convertView.getTag(); } txt.setText(data.get(position).getTexto());` ... if you are using more views use holder pattern ... next take a look at ArrayAdapter ... there is a Filter implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because you are not following the `ViewHolder` design pattern in the `Adapter`. Now do the following 
Add the below class as an inner class of your `Adapter`

```
static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView texto;
}
```

and replace your `getView()` method of your adapter with the following

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.celda_listview_tributos, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.texto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.texto.setText(data.get(position).getTexto());
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Its working ok now. Thank you! I need to read about the ViewHolder pattern, Ive been always doing my adapters without it. Time to read :)